# Element not interactable (but visible and correct path) - Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm writing a script with Python to enter a website and navigate through it. The problem is that I want to click on an element but looks like it's not interactable.

The path is correct, the website has time to load and the element is visible so I don't understand what is happening.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver_service = Service(executable_path="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")

link = "https://my_link.com"
username = "user"
password = "pass"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,service=driver_service)

driver.get(link)
 
time.sleep(10)

driver.find_element(By.NAME, "username").send_keys(username)
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password").send_keys(password)

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[type="submit"]').click()

time.sleep(15)

driver.get(link)

time.sleep(10)

rel_path_1 = "//span[contains(text(),'XHRC001')]"

element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, rel_path_1)
element.click()
```

DOM PHOTO:

[image: DOM PHOTO]

Comment: An error message you're getting would be helpful to help you further. Possible things that you could try to fix your problem would be to use an explicit wait or if the site uses bot protection you could try using undetected-chromedriver to bypass that bot protection.

Comment: it can be helpful if you provide url or dom photo

Comment: @RomanJ I also tried an explicit wait but delete that part of the code cause still got the TimeoutException error.

Comment: @federikowsky I have just edited it and added a photo.

Comment: since it is not possible to see the site, the causes for which it does not work can be various. Using `//tag[contains(text(), ...)]` it is possible that there are multiple elements that match and this will return the first one. The tag you highlighted doesn't appear to be an editable or interactable field, so `click()` may not work for that and selenium should throw something like `ElementNotInteractableException`. continue..

Comment: If something happens when clicked instead it is possible that there is a javascript event on that element, in which case you could consider using `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", rel_path_1)` to run javascript command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be multiple reasons, try the below options:

1. Locate element manually by inspecting DOM, steps below:

   1)Press <kbd>F12</kbd> on the application windiw

   2)Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

   3)Paste the XPATH expression (`//span[contains(text(),'XHRC001')]`)

   4)If it locates just one element, you are good to go to below steps, else your issue is in the XPATH which you need to fix
2. Check for the presence of IFRAME which is wrapping the desired element. If it exists, you need to switch into it first and then act on the element:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"<xpath of the iframe>>")))
```

3. Apply `Waits` with the condition `element_to_be_clickable`:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[contains(text(),'XHRC001')]")))
```

4. Try to `click()` using Javascript:

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'XHRC001')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Comment: Really good explanation, it was all inside one iframe so I added that line and even changed the PATH to
`//span[contains(@class, 'inner-ghhqKDrt symbolNameText-ghhqKDrt') and text()='XHRC001']`
But still after selecting the frame I', having problems with step 3. It runs out of time, I tried just to click on it and the error is caused because its Unable to locate element.

Comment: Can you share the HTML of IFRAME and your latest code? Share the HTML and code in the form of text not image/photo.

Comment: I made a small change and everything works except the last line.
`element = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, 'inner-ghhqKDrt symbolNameText-ghhqKDrt') and text()='XHRC003']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
`
The problem is  `javascript error: arguments[0].click is not a function`. I don't understand why is that happening.

Comment: Change `find_elements` to `find_element` and give it a try.

Comment: With `find_element` it's unable to locate element.

Comment: Finally got the answer, I'm using `find_element` but not `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)`. Instead I'm just using `element.click()`. So I guess the main issue was waiting and switching to the correct iframe.